# Can I select elements that have a class (any class)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a selector that selects elements having any class unlike `:not([class])`?

I am using [Adobe DTM](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/c_overview.html) to define rules and events that will fire a particular request in Adobe Analytics. One of my rules is activated each time the user clicks an element with a `data-analytics-linkname` attribute in the tag, and the following elements would trigger the rule for example:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_self" class="btn btn-default" data-analytics-linkname="visit_Google">Visit Google</a>

<a href="www.google.com" target="_self" data-analytics-linkname="visit_Google">Visit Google</a>
```

I'm aware of the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class selector, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with any browser.

Only the link with the defined class (`btn`) should trigger the class. However, I do not really want to specify class `btn` in my rules, as I want to be as flexible as possible with them, and I do not want to create one each time the developers create a new asset.

Comment: No there isn't AFAIK...`:has()` is not adopted as yet. You're trying to *exclude* certain elements which is precisely what `:not()` was created for. If you need to NOT apply then class, the you'll have to limit the "click" with Javascript to the item clicked,

Comment: what do you mean ***"an opposite of `:not([class])` to select elements without class at all"?*** thats precisely what `:not([class])` does, it selects everything without a class attribute...?

Comment: @Anthony you are right... I edited the question, so right now it is "any class" and not "without class at all"

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes I suppose that the better solution is to tell the developers to remove the data-analytics-linkname attribute to the only text elements (without class)

Comment: `:not([class])` selects elements that does not have a class attribute. The opposite of that, selecting elements that DO have a class attribute would be simply `[class]`

Comment: @Lennholm before in his question he said "...to select elements WITHOUT class at all?"

Comment: You say you only want to select links that have `btn` class, but you don't want to have to reference `btn` in the selector? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: *"...and I do not want to create one each time the developers create a new asset."* You need to communicate with those developers if that is possible. Trying to avoid common standards like class is a battle you will lose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all elements with a certain attribute by using the attribute present selector `[...]`. If you specify `a[class]`, all `a` elements ***with*** the `class` attribute will be selected.

```css
a[class] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">Button 1</a>
<a class="btn2">Button 2</a>
<a>Button 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fairly straight forward, simply `[class]` or something like `[class]:not(body)`.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

[class]:not(body) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='t1'></div>
<div class='t2'></div>
<button class='t3'>button 1</button>
<div></div>
<button>button 2</button>
```

Your problem doesn't make a lot of sense. If you don't want to use the `btn` class as a selector to remain as flexible as possible, and don't want to create one each time the developers create a new asset, simply create and use a another class strictly for that purpose.